# Want to Send Multiple request using Single Socket In TCP/IP protocol?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, buffer, bytearrayoutputstream

Here I created a fan activity and every time when I Click to any button
    It Start Fan-Socket class and create a new Socket on every click button.
    But I am getting a delay when I Click buttons continueosly.
    how can I Send a multiple request using single Socket and on each button 
    click how can I send a msg string through the Socket??
    Is there is Something that creating a buffer and putting a value in
     that buffer and call each buffer value on every click.
    if it so How can I do that.. ?? 
    Kindly help me to solve this issue as 
    I am new in android programming I can not able to solve this problem 
    from several day

Fan Activity:

```
       public class FAN extends AppCompatActivity {
  private   Button buttonOn;
  private   Button button1;

     @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(layout.activity_fan);
    buttonOn = (Button) findViewById(id.Buttonon);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

   buttonOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (turnOn) {
                 int tmpInt = 2;
                 String FAN = String.valueOf(tmpInt); //Converting int to string.
                 FAN_SOCKET b1 = new FAN_SOCKET();  // calling class fan socket
                 b1.execute(FAN);  //calling fan-socket class and pass the the 2 value through it. 
                 turnOn = false;
              }
             else {
                    int tmpInt = 0;
                    String FAN = String.valueOf(tmpInt); //Converting int to string.
                    FAN_SOCKET b1 = new FAN_SOCKET();  // calling class fan socket
                      b1.execute(FAN);  //sending value to socket.
                      turnOn = true;
              }
           }
        });
```

Fan-Socket Class:

```
   class FAN_SOCKET extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

    Socket socket = null;
    PrintWriter pw;
    String response;

 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(String... voids) {
        String massage = null;
         try {
            massage = voids[0];
           socket = new Socket("192.168.0.79",8888 );
          pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
              pw.write(massage);
           try {
              pw.flush();
             pw.close();
            socket.close();

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       return null;
    }
}
```